# Lectura de lineas de fichero de texto con pausas cada 25 lineas

Tags: c#, consola

Estoy haciendo un programa que lea 25 lineas de mi fichero de texto y que al darle enter me muestre las otras 25, ya lee las primeras 25 pero al darle enter se cierra el programa, alguien que me ayude por favor?

```
        StreamReader fichero;
        string nombre;
        int i = 0; ;

        Console.Write("Escribe el nombre del fichero (\"fin\"para terminar);");
            nombre = Console.ReadLine();

            if (File.Exists(nombre))

            {

                fichero = File.OpenText(nombre);
                int j = 0;
                while (i <= 25)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(nombre);
                    nombre = fichero.ReadLine();
                    if (i % 25 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.ReadKey();

                }
                i++;
            }
        Console.ReadKey();

        } 

            else
                Console.WriteLine("No existe");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Tu error está en la condición del while. Debieras mantenerte en el while mientras haya más líneas en el archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya se cual fue mi error, ya lo arregle